# Updated state not reflecting in dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm setting the state of contact then dispatching the state to the store but the state that is dispatched is empty while the state in my component is updated. This is in the callback too so not sure why it's not updated... am I missing something? Thanks everyone.

```
        if (showForm === true) {
        const {contact} = this.state;
        this.setState({ contact: shipInfo, showForm: !showForm }, () => {
            dispatch(updateContact(contact));
            this.formValidation();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `const { contact } = this.state`, then using that version of `contact` to send to the store.  But that is not the updated variable.  It sounds like what you want to do is send

```js
dispatch(updateContact(shipInfo));
```

which is what you're updating your variable to become in the next state.

Another way of writing would be:

```js
        this.setState({ contact: shipInfo, showForm: !showForm }, () => {
            const { contact } = this.state;
            dispatch(updateContact(contact));
            this.formValidation();
        });
```

Now you're grabbing the newer version of state, as you're defining it from within your callback, where state has already been updated.

Comment: Thank you!! Didn't think it mattered where I brought in this.state.contact. Bringing in after setState worked. You the maaaaaaan.

Comment:  yes its very important where you declare your variables. variable scope and function closures - learn them, love them